# Is ROS answer able to join stackexchange?

Tags: ros, meta, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because I can use stackexchange's function to see message on whatever board.

If ROS answer can join them, I can receive notice message on any of stackexchange board.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12386/is-ros-answer-able-to-join-stackexchange?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-12-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, OSQA/Askbot is not compatible with Stackexchange.

If you are explicitly looking for a Robotics QNA site on Stackexchange, [Robotics Research](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29987/robotics-research) is in the commitment phase of it's launch currently.  It is not a ROS community like this one is, but a more general robotics QNA hosted on stack exchange.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-12-19**:
I don't think there is any fix to this.  Some people just don't agree with the way that Stack Exchange works, and want more control over their communities.  I don't think that it is a high priority for either OSQA/Askbot or Stack Exchange to add this feature.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-12-18**:
Is there any way to suggest them to fix this uncompatible? If yes,this way will also attract more people to use stackexchange.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-07-04**:
What's the big difference between both? From my user point of view they do the same thing - I can ask questions and people answer. I also think adding the ROS Q&A to stack exchange would be a good idea!

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-08-16**:
Now, [robotics.stackexchange.com](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) is the general robotics platform in stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See

http://www.ros.org/news/2011/02/announcing-ros-answers.html

https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110208.182812.07530210.en.html

http://robotics-worldwide.1046236.n5.nabble.com/robotics-worldwide-Robotics-Stackexchange-td5706992.html

Some reasons that would make it hard / bad to migrate:

- Unless there is an undocumented fast-track, we'd need to suffer through the area 51 staging zone, where we cannot have our own css styles etc.
- Effort to migrate existing Questions and answers to a stack-exchange ROS site and make sure user accounts in answers.ros.org match user accounts in stack exchange
  and also keep URLs for questions remain the same (such as used for marking duplicates).
- External hosting downtimes cannot be fixed by ourselves
- External hosting means we have less control over our data
- stackexchange is not open-source, while askbot is, and the ROS community prefers to foster open-source projects to closed-source
- it is easier to get customizations by Askbot maintainers

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7